# Как разместить item в toolbar'e по середине?

Tags: android, toolbar

Не могу найти как. Думал можно как атрибут веса поставить, но его нет.

Comment: Никак. Тулбар такое не поддерживает. Не используйте его для этого, а сверстайте макет из обычных вью

Comment: @ЮрийСПб возможно автор имел в виду текст в toolbar'e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зайдите в ваш `string` файл, удалите имя вашего приложения из строки `app_name`

```
  <string name="app_name"></string>
```

Затем откройте ваш `activity_main` в котором прописан `toolbar`, добавтье в него `textview`

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="НАЗВАНИЕ_ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

и закройте после этого `textview` тег `toolbarа`.

```
   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте с помощью параметра [gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html):

```
android:gravity="center"
```